# unable to change the permisson of an file in linux

Tags: linux

Unable to change the permission of the cgi-bin. I want that folder to have write option for user too

```
abc@abc:~/public_html> ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root  4096 2013-10-24 11:16 cgi-bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 john users  835 2013-10-24 15:54 index.html
```

when i write

```
abc@abc:~/public_html> chmod 770 cgi-bin
```

error:

chmod: changing permissions of `cgi-bin': Operation not permitted

Comment: As `cgi-bin` belongs to user root, you need to use `sudo` or root itself to change permissions of that file.

Comment: what should i write ??

Comment: `sudo chmod 770 cgi-bin` or `sudo su -` and then `chmod 770 cgi-bin`. But you have to be in the sudoers file to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
sudo chmod 770 cgi-bin
```

or to recursively change all files in the folder

```
sudo chmod -R 770 cgi-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 dirpath/filename
```

Comment: if you use the -R command it will recursively change so if you use dirpath/filename then the -R command wouldn't really be needed